# How to declare other responce then 200 by Google Endpoints Api annotations?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

..so that maven generated OpenAPI.json reflects it? Well it really seems to me like it is not possibe but.. I need to use OpenAPI.json as real documentation and do not feel manually edit every time is best option?

Comment: You can use the Endpoints API to throw exceptions to return other response codes as described in the [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/exceptions). An example of how to do it in Java can be seen [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/endpoints-v1-helloworld/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/YourFirstAPI.java#L128).

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I might formulate my question not well. I use those exceptions. My concern was how to produce openapi.json so that i can share it as a document for API including all responce codes. I mean openapi.json which is generated automaticaly by mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You can submit a feature request for [Java](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java) or [Python](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python).

Comment: I have submited, thands for advice.